# How to Access Peachtree Database in Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework

I want to access Peachtree Database into Zend Framework. I have installed Zend Framework and Peachtree Premium Trial Version. Now I want to access the database of Peachtree into Zend Framework. Please provide some link or code to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

According to its website, Peachtree uses the Pervasive PSQL embedded database.

To access Pervasive PSQL from PHP, one could try PHP's ODBC extension.  This is the recommended connection solution mentioned on http://ww1.pervasive.com/developerzone/development_env/php.asp

Zend Framework tracked a [feature request](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-905) to implement an ODBC adapter for Zend_Db, chiefly to support Microsoft SQL Server.  The hope was that this would also allow connecting to any RDBMS that had an ODBC driver.

But work on the ODBC adapter feature was abandoned after a specific Microsoft SQL Server adapter was written for Zend_Db, about July 2009.

So I don't think there is any path to integrate the Peachtree database with Zend Framework classes.